# "Of" from Dutch to French?

Tags: conjonctions, coordination, néerlandais, pronoms-interrogatifs

I don't know how to translate the word "of" to French in some cases?

> Ik vroeg me af OF hij dat wel moest doen.

And you also have

> Wil jij een ijsje OF heb je liever een wafel?

What's the difference between the 2 "OF" in French? In Dutch, it is called "nevenschikkend voegwoord" and "onderschikkend voegwoord".
And  what's the translation of it?

EDIT: I tried to translate it to English, but it may be wrongly translated.

> I asked myself IF he should do that.

And the other:

> Do you want an ice cream OR do you prefer a woffle?

Comment: We don't speak dutch... can you translate it into english first ? What does google translate say about it ?

Comment: Google Translate makes it completly wrong :/

Comment: Isn't it "moet" ?

Comment: And what about [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/neerlandais-francais/OF/forced) you can choose the languages...   does OF mean [or](http://dictionary.reverso.net/dutch-english/OF) in English?

Comment: Well, I tried to translate it, but it can be wrong

Comment: if = si ; 
or = ou. I think it's as simple as that.

Comment: And no, it isn't "moet", it should be "moest".

Comment: Ah yes, you're right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a sentence between two items at the same "level", "of" will be translated as "ou"

> ja of nee
>
> Wil jij een ijsje OF heb je liever een wafel?

=

> oui ou non
>
> Veux-tu une glace (crème glacée) OU préfères-tu une gaufre?

In French there is no construction where "ou" doesn't put the two items at the same level ("ou" is always a "conjonction de coordination"). Your first example is a "subordonnée" (bijzin in Dutch), which is then introduced by "si" in French.

> Ik vroeg me af of hij dat wel moest doen.
>
> Je me demandais s'il devait vraiment le faire.

Note that "s'il" is a contraction of "si il".

Comment: "Si il" is *not* correct, elision is mandatory here.

Comment: Nitpicking : "jiliagre" and "autant pour moi" are not correct, should be "jlliagre" and "au temps pour moi" : http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#16_strong-em-au-temps-pour-moi-em-strong

Comment: @jlliagre au temps pour moi (bis)